# "Member not found" error in IE6: from .style edit or getElementById or...?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I volunteered to develop this script for a small organisation (as part of my self-training in programming). It randomly selects a seat in a room (spending a few seconds keeping viewers guessing which seat was selected). Since I use a Mac, I tested mainly with Firefox, where it works like a charm. Turns out that the computer in their room runs Internet Explorer 6 on Windows XP (and they had to enable active content in local files).

They called me to inform me of an error and based on the information they gave, the guilty line is either `RowNumberDisplay.style = "color: #FF0000";` or `var RowNumberDisplay = document.getElementById("RowNumber");`. Quick searches on Google and Stack Overflow for getElementById and .style problems in IE6 were fruitless (a common problem is false matches due to name attributes, but the div in question has no name attribute). Thanks in advance for any answers helping identify and address this error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The Lucky Person</title>
            <style type="text/css">
            input#SelectLuckyPerson
            {
                height: 150px;
                font-size: 60px;
            }
            p#RowDetails, p#SeatDetails, div#RowNumber, div#SeatNumber
            {
                font-size: 100px;
                display: inline;
            }
            div#RowNumber, div#SeatNumber
            {
                color: #0000FF;
            }
            </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="LuckyPersonIs"><input type="button" id="SelectLuckyPerson" value="And the lucky person is..." onClick="GetResults();"></div>
        <p id="RowDetails">Row number: <div id="RowNumber">0</div></p>
        <p id="SeatDetails">Seat number: <div id="SeatNumber">0</div></p>
        <script>
            var MinRow = 2;
            var MaxRow = 8;
            var SeatsInRow = new Array();
            SeatsInRow[1] = 25;
            SeatsInRow[2] = 25;
            SeatsInRow[3] = 27;
            SeatsInRow[4] = 27;
            SeatsInRow[5] = 27;
            SeatsInRow[6] = 27;
            SeatsInRow[7] = 29;
            SeatsInRow[8] = 31;
            SeatsInRow[9] = 31;
            SeatsInRow[10] = 31;
            SeatsInRow[11] = 31;
            SeatsInRow[12] = 33;
            SeatsInRow[13] = 33;
            SeatsInRow[14] = 33;
            var ShuffleSpeed = 200;
            var RowNumberDisplay = document.getElementById("RowNumber");
            var SeatNumberDisplay = document.getElementById("SeatNumber");
            var ChosenRow, ChosenSeat
            function GetResults()
            {
                var IsRunning = CheckStatus();
                if (IsRunning)
                {
                    ChosenRow = ChooseRow();
                    ChosenSeat = ChooseSeat();
                    RowNumberDisplay.style = "color: #FF0000";
                    SeatNumberDisplay.style = "color: #FF0000";
                    ShowRowResult = window.setInterval("TryRowResult()", ShuffleSpeed);
                    if (DelaySeats == false)
                    {
                        ShowSeatResult = window.setInterval("TrySeatResult()", ShuffleSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }
            function ChooseRow()
            {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (MaxRow - MinRow)) + MinRow;
            }
            function ChooseSeat()
            {
                return Math.ceil(Math.random() * SeatsInRow[ChosenRow]);
            }
            function TryRowResult()
            {
                TryRow = ChooseRow();
                RowNumberDisplay.innerHTML = TryRow;
                if (TryRow == ChosenRow)
                {
                    window.clearInterval(ShowRowResult);
                    document.getElementById("RowNumber").style = "color: #0000FF";
                    if (DelaySeats == true)
                    {
                        ShowSeatResult = window.setInterval("TrySeatResult()", ShuffleSpeed);
                    }
                }
            }
            function TrySeatResult()
            {
                TrySeat = ChooseSeat();
                SeatNumberDisplay.innerHTML = TrySeat;
                if (TrySeat == ChosenSeat)
                {
                    window.clearInterval(ShowSeatResult);
                    document.getElementById("SeatNumber").style = "color: #0000FF";
                }
            }
            function CheckStatus()
            {
                if (RowNumberDisplay.style.color == "rgb(255, 0, 0)" || SeatNumberDisplay.style.color == "rgb(255, 0, 0)")
                {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
            </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You know, if I were working on something, and the people I was making it for insisted on still using IE6? I'd throw the project spec at them and leave. People like that are not worth the time we developers are forced to sacrifice just because they can't be arsed to hit the "Update" button.

Comment: WinXP can get at least IE8 and definetly Chrome or FF. Or is it not an option for them?

Comment: They are in the middle of an upgrading programme but have not got to the computer in that room yet. Turns out that IE8 also gives the same error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An element's `style` property is an object, not a string. To assign text to it like you would a CSS attribute, you should assign to `element.style.cssText`, this will parse out the string for you, and acts as a shortcut to defining multiple styles.

In this case, though, you can just use this:

```
ChosenRow.style.color = ChosenSeat.style.color = "#f00";
```

Comment: Thanks! Awaiting their confirmation whether this works. Will tick your answer if it does.